# ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile and dependent functions

Tags: sharpdx

Moving from the old Effects Framework to the new world of SharpDX 3 (which has no effects framework) means I need to re-work my effect compilation. My old effect files have VS and PS entry points and the Shaderbytecode.CompileFromFile deals with this - but I'm trying to track down a bug where I have shaders which have dependent functions (which might be related to the bug - I'm just trying to eliminate possibilities).

Question : when compiling an entry point with Shaderbytecode.CompileFromFile does the resulting bytecode contain all the instructions for the dependent functions as well ? ShaderReflection on the bytecode doesn't help to find this out, so hoping someone will know the definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question for reference;

Yes - if you remove a dependent function from the HLSL source, the compiler will throw an error. Although this doesn't prove the bytecode contains the instructions for the function, its clearly being compiled.